# limit of a geometric-type series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I came across this series while studying probability theory.

Let $$T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right),$$

where $T(x)$ converges for some range of $x$.

My question is how to prove that $T(x)=1+\frac{1-x}{x}\log(1-x)$ for all $|x|<1$.

The following is my attempt.

---

It is tempting to differentiate $T$ w.r.t. $x$, which I cannot justify because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} \frac{1}{n+1}$ is not uniformly convergent in $(-1,1)$:

$$T'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1} \frac{1}{n+1}.$$

It is also tempting to do the followings:

$$x^2 T'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1} \frac{1}{n+1}:=P(x)$$

and differentiate $P(x)$ to get:

$$P'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}.$$

So, $P(x)=\int P'(x)dx=-x-\log(|x-1|)+C$, where $C$ is a constant, cf. [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-integral-of-X-1-x).

Then we have $T'(x)=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\log(|x-1|)}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x^2}$. But I don't know how to integrate the second term to recover $T(x)$.

Another crucial problem with my attempt is that, every step is formal and we lost track of the radius of convergence of $x$. Kind of being stuck here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can't we just split $T(x)$ into $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n$ and $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1} = -\frac1x\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}n$ and evaluate them separately, using the known Maclaurin series for $\log(1-x)$ that's valid for $|x|<1$?

Comment: A useful fact: to differentiate under the sum it is enough that the convergence is locally uniform! (The derivative is, after all, a local operation) .
Also for the final integration, since $x\in(-1,1)$, write $\log(|x-1|)=\log(1-x)$ and an integration by parts should be enough. The constant $C$ is determined from the fact that $P(0)=0=P'(0)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Sure. I was lost in probability theory and forgot the elementary stuff.

Comment: @GiulioR Nice point. By locally uniform, you mean there exists a small neighborhood at every point in the domain and the sum is uniformly convergent in that neighborhood, right?

Comment: Exactly, that;s enough to take the derivative inside the sum (plus other minor conditions that are easily verified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the known series for on(1-x) and elementary series rearrangements?

$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$ for $-1<x\le 1$
so
\begin{align*}
T(x) 
&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)
\\&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1}
\\&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}
\\&=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{1}{x}\left(-x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\right)
\\&=
-\ln(1-x) + 1 + \frac{1}{x}\ln(1-x)
\\&=
1 + \frac{1-x}{x}\ln(1-x)
\end{align*}

All steps are valid for $-1<x<1$, except possibly x=0 (but either think of it a removable singularity or check the original equation at x=0).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yea, by L'Hospital, we see $x=0$ is a removable singularity.

Answer (score 3):

$$T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n(n+1)}=\frac 1{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)} $$
$$\big(x\,T(x)\big)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n}}{n}=\log(1-x)$$

Integrate both sides